# Can NV_path_rendering extension be used in OpenGL 4+ Core profile?

Tags: opengl, nvidia

I have been reading [the docs](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering) regarding the usage of NVidia NV_path_rendering  extension.What is not clear for me is whether it can work in OpenGL 4 an greater core profile.I am unsure about it because in the supplied examples I could see a usage of the fixed pipeline (matrices ,colors).Also it is stated that that all the shader stages but fragment are discarded during path render step.Are those methods extension specific or they come from the fixed GL API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [extension specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/path_rendering.txt):

> For OpenGL 3.x and up, ARB_compatibility is required.

So no. NVIDIA doesn't expose ARB_compatibility if you ask for a core profile.

Comment: I just  tested the extension.It does work with Core profile but methods like glColor3f have no effect.The shapes are rendered with black/white color.Thanks for the answer.